# Blazor InputFile IFileListEntry cannot be found

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

With the coming .net5.0 I have started learning blazor. I want to convert a project. The problem is file upload.

I need to allow users to upload images and small data files.

I am using [these examples](https://blog.stevensanderson.com/2019/09/13/blazor-inputfile/)

```
<InputFile id="uploadFolder" OnChange="HandleSelection" />

@code {   
    IFileListEntry[] selectedFiles;
    
    void HandleSelection(IFileListEntry[] files)
    {
        selectedFiles = files;    
    }
}
```

> Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'IFileListEntry' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) WebApplication6.Client G:\ Blazor\WebApplication6\WebApplication6\Client\Pages\Index.razor 11 Active

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong docs. That was the prototype used I believe for 5.0. Please use the [latest documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0#inputfile-component).

Your code should look something like this now:

```
<InputFile multiple OnChange="HandleSelection" />

@code {

    IReadOnlyList<IBrowserFile> selectedFiles;

    void HandleSelection(InputFileChangeEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        const int MaxAllowedFiles = 5;
        selectedFiles = eventArgs.GetMultipleFiles(MaxAllowedFiles);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thankyou by chance do you know to select a folder?

Comment: There is a way to select folders. Put what you have tried in another question. We are not here to write your code.